# Web application providing the wrong certificate of another application's certificate

Tags: asp.net, https, ssl-certificate, iis-10, windows-server-2019

We have several ASP.net web applications on IIS 10, and all apps have their own certificates. However after we created the URL rewrite rule to force http to https, it worked perfectly, however after we mistakenly clicked on "revert to parent". Now every web application is using the last configured certificate. for example we have A,B ,C,D apps on IIS.

A is using A.domain.local certificate

B is using B.domain.local certificate

C is using C.domain.local certificate

D is not configured yet

now if we assign a certificate to the D app, which will use D.domain.local certificate, after we apply the certificate on bindings of D app, all the other apps (A,B, and C) will use the D certificate.
now I go back to A apps, and change the certificate back to A certificate, all the other apps will have changed their certificates to A. and so on. What I've done wrong? what to do? the system is down now, I tried to reinstall the IIS without any success. your support please.

Answer (score -1):

You accidentally broke the certificate mappings in Windows HTTP API, and that's why even reinstalling IIS won't help.

Use `netsh` command or Jexus Manager to remove all related mappings first,

https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/https-binding.html#sni-based-bindings

and then you can go back and add SNI bindings back once again.